# Permalinks making images throwing 404 errors (3 posts)

Tags: wordpress, iis, permalinks

I am running Wordpress 4.1. I chose the "Day and name" option for the permalinks for my site, in order for the URL to appear in "pretty" form.

However, it is giving me a problem. I notice if I use that option, all my images are throwing 404 errors. My images are uploaded into the Media Library.

I am running the site locally in IIS. I have installed the URL ReWrite Module in IIS 7.5 already

what should I do to avoid this problem? Should I add an image handler in web.config? for those of you who had this problem, please help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you updated your permalinks - just change it to another value save and then back again and save - sometimes this helps. Also, could you please post an example of the URL that throws a 404 and what it should be?

Comment: This is my URL Link http://cpb.localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/HomeSlider3.jpg

Comment: This is my web.config that has URL Rewrite

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?page_id={R:0}"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem. There is an option called 'fastcgi.impersonate' in your php.ini file that does not get set correctly in the latest PHP installer for windows. I also noticed that all of the sized images that are generated when you upload to the media library were able to load, just not the original image.

You need todo 3 things:
1) Add the rewrite rule if you already haven't
2) Open php.ini and set 'fastcgi.impersonate=1' and restart IIS
3) Ensure the 'IIS_IUSRS' group has modify permissions to the 'wp-content' folder

I fixed this before images were uploaded so you may have to change the permissions for the entire uploads folder if you have pre-existing content.